# Right align inside header

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, fancyhdr

I have a header, prepared using `fancyhdr`. I would like the first row of the left header to be right-aligned with the second row of the left header.
In the following MWE I would like "My City" to be right aligned with "University of somewhere" (so that "City" is just above "somewhere"). How do I achieve that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\textsc{Tutorial\\The periodic table}}
\lhead{\textsc{My city\\University of somewhere}}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}
    hello
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can box the contents of the widest element and use this to width-adjust the shorter one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\newsavebox{\myheadbox}% Heading storage box

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\textsc{Tutorial\\The periodic table}}
\lhead{\textsc{\savebox{\myheadbox}{University of somewhere}\makebox[\wd\myheadbox][r]{My city}\\\usebox{\myheadbox}}}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}
    hello
\end{document}​
```

`\myheadbox` contains the "University of somewhere" (in the appropriate font, `\scshape`). Then, "My city" is `r`ight-aligned in a `\makebox` of width `\wd\myheadbox` (width of `\myheadbox`).

Answer (score 8):

Don't load `fancyheadings`, which is the obsolete version of `fancyhdr`.

The easiest way is to use `tabular` which will take care of the alignment:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[R]{%
  \scshape
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}
  Tutorial\\The periodic table
  \end{tabular}}
\fancyhead[L]{%
  \scshape
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}
  My city\\University of somewhere
  \end{tabular}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
```

Set the `\headheight` to the value that `fancyhdr` will show you in the .log file. For a 10pt document it says to do

```
\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You may typeset the left header `\raggedleft` inside a `minipage` with a width of the widest element (calculated with the help of `\widthof`, which is provided by the [`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) package).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{calc}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\textsc{Tutorial\\The periodic table}}
\lhead{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\widthof{\textsc{University of somewhere}}}
  \raggedleft
  \textsc{My city\\University of somewhere}%
  \end{minipage}
}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}
    hello
\end{document}
```

EDIT: As pointed out by egreg in chat, one may replace the `minipage` with a `varwidth` environment *"whose resulting width is the natural width of its contents"* (package manual).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\textsc{Tutorial\\The periodic table}}
\lhead{%
  \begin{varwidth}[b]{10cm}
  \raggedleft
  \textsc{My city\\University of somewhere}%
  \end{varwidth}
}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}
    hello
\end{document}
```

Output for both examples:

[image]